# General solution for differential equation with assumed form $x^p$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

$x^2u'' + xu' + (2+\lambda)u = 0$

and the solution provided says to assume $u=x^p$ which leads to

$p^2=-(2+\lambda)$ and then jumps to

$u = A\cos(\sqrt{2 +\lambda}\log(x)) + B\sin(\sqrt{2 +\lambda}\log(x))$

I can see that it clearly is a solution but I have no idea how the $\log(x)$ got in there.

Comment: It is just a way to rewrite $x^p$ when p is complex.

Comment: Sometimes the (ultimately unsatisfying) answer is "because it works".

Comment: I've seen $e^{ix} = cos(x) + isin(x)$ but I'm not very familiar with the same being done for $x^p$. Could you provide a source that outlines the derivation for $x^{ip}$? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: $x^p=(e^{\ln x})^p=e^{p\cdot \ln x}$.

Comment: @smmr Do note though that although $e^z$ is uniquely defined for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $x^z$ is not uniquely defined for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$ or even all $x \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. The reason is that in the formula $x^p=e^{p \ln(x)}$, $\ln(x)$ is itself not uniquely defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2u'' + xu' + (2+\lambda)u = 0$$

$$p^2=-(2+\lambda)\implies$$

$$ p=\pm  i\sqrt {2+\lambda}$$

$$ u= x^p= e^{p \ln x} $$

$$ u_1=e^{ i\sqrt {2+\lambda}\ln x}=\cos (\sqrt {2+\lambda}\ln x)+ i\sin (\sqrt {2+\lambda}\ln x)  $$

Where we have used the Euler's

$$ e^{i\theta}=\cos (\theta)+i\sin (\theta)$$

and

$$u_2=e^{ i\sqrt {2+\lambda}\ln x}=\cos (\sqrt {2+\lambda}\ln x)- i\sin (\sqrt {2+\lambda}\ln x)  $$

And the rest is clear.